# Issue from keeping values with subtotal function

Tags: excel, vba

Do you know how do I keep the subtotal function from changing when I re-filter cells?

```
' Variable pour trouver la dernière ligne
    Dim DernLigne As Long
    DernLigne = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Insérer Montant HT en G
    Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$17874").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="**FR240**" 'Filter sur FR240
    Sheets("IML").Select
    Range("G" & DernLigne).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,'DETAIL MAG'!C[11])"
```

When I do the same function with another filter to the next row, it changes my previous cells.

```
' Variable pour trouver la dernière ligne
        Dim DernLigne As Long
        DernLigne = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Insérer Montant HT en G
        Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$17874").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="**FR0S0**" 'Filter sur FR0S0
        Sheets("IML").Select
        Range("G" & DernLigne).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,'DETAIL MAG'!C[11])"
```

Maybe another function would be better ?

Comment: Range specified in second function is same as range specified in first function, that's why it changes it. You would need to respecify last row "DernLigne". Last row should be specified after filter not before. Beside that - Since both criteria are for the same function best way would be to add OR Criteria for ex. `Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=<>A", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=<>B"`  and then in this range do the function

Comment: Thanks for your help @p77u77n77k . I added the last row("DernLigne") after the filter, but the values is still changing

Comment: As you are using a non-explicit range when getting the last row, this could be the issue. Make `Range`, `Rows` etc **always explicit** by adding the according sheet to them, e.g. `DernLigne = Sheets("IML").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store sum of filtered data in dim and then paste it in range/cell where you want it :).

For first iteration/function/part it would be

```
Dim FR240 As Range
Dim SUM_FR240 As Long
Dim DernLigne As Long

DernLigne = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
Set FR240 = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A1:U17874") 'setting whole range of data
Sheets("DETAIL MAG").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filters
FR240.AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="**FR240**" 'filtering data
SUM_FR240 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("C2:C" & DernLigne).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) 'summing filtered data
```

If you want to place it in cell then just go with `Sheets("IML").Cells("G1") = SUM_FR240` or other.

Do the same for the second function and place the sum in different cell/range

Answer (score 0):

It works well, but it’s rounding the Numbers when I copy the filtered data in a cell.
Do you know how to stop Rounding Numbers ?

```
Dim FR520 As Range  
Dim SUM_FR520 As Long   
Dim DernLigne As Long DernLigne = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row 
Set FR520 = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A1:U17874") 'setting whole range of data
Sheets("DETAIL MAG").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filters 
FR520.AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="FR520" 'filtering data SUM_FR520 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("R1:R" & DernLigne).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) 'summing filtered data
 
Range("G" & DernLigne).Value = SUM_FR520
```

In cell G I have "4367,00" instead of "4367,24"

Comment: `Dim Sum_FR520 As Double`. `Long` data type do not store decimals

Comment: Great, it's working ! Thank you @RaymondWu :)

Comment: Note: If you need a clarification on an answer, post it as a comment to follow up instead of posting another answer (which is actually another query)